# C# web forms - How to pass data from master page to master page when redirect is on web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, response.redirect

When on master page I have dropDownList with event. When event Raise I want to load/redirect webForm.aspx. In this webForm.aspx I want to load data based on dropDownList selected item. At the same time I want to load again dropDownList and select Item on which clicked was.

I created some solution, where I was using Response.Redirect("webform.aspx?courseID=4") on masterPage.

Is this good approach to this problem? I think there must be better, but I cant see  it.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Is your MasterPage checking the querystring to grab the courseID, and update the dropDownList accordingly?

Comment: In MastePage- Page_Load when !Page.IsPostback I have function where I load everything from database and if there is response context courseID, then i read his value and set active item by value in dropDownList which worked. Now I tried to do response with Route system, but Page.RouteData.Values["courseID"] as string; in masterPage has nothing  in it.

Comment: Depends, if it's safe to include the value in the URL, it's a perfectly legit way of moving the value around, here's a link to all the standard ways of moving data between web forms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Comment: Yes, number is safe, I am checking it if its only number and have stored procedures. For that second question. Does anybody know why I cant display RouteData Value according to my problem(from MasterPage sending Response `Response.Redirect(Page.GetRouteUrl("CourseSelected", new { courseID = ddlCourse.SelectedValue }));`, with route registered `routes.MapPageRoute("CourseSelected", "Course/{courseID}", "~/Course.aspx");` and  `ddlCourse.SelectedValue = Page.RouteData.Values["courseID"] as string;` in MasterPage)?

Answer (score 1):

One way is your solution: to use *querystring*.

The second way is: on dropdownlist's value changing you changing value of some session value (e.g. *Session["course_id"]), then *Response.Redirect("webform.aspx")* and restore by *Session["course_id"]* value.

```
protected void ddlCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session["course_id"] = ddlCourses.SelectedValue;
    Response.Redirect("webform.aspx");
}
```

ABOUT YOUR SECOND QUESTION (HOW TO TAKE ROUTE VALUE FROM MASTER PAGE). I will give just brief explanation and a little example.

Create in your master page some method:

```
protected void IWantToWarkWithRouteValue(){
    //here you will do something
    //and to take value from routing, just use Session["myValue"] (I will explain this value later)
}
```

You should call this method in *Page_Load*, not in *Pre_Init* or *Init*

Then in your *Course.aspx* (caz' you using routing here) create the next method:

```
protected void SetCourseSessionFromTheRoute(){
    if (Page.RouteData.Values["courseID"] != null)
        Session["myValue"] = Page.RouteData.Values["courseID"].ToString();
}
```

And call this method in *Page_PreInit*:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e){
    SetCourseSessionFromTheRoute();
}
```

Thanksgiving to ASP.NET page's life cycle, you may do anything you need.

You may read about page's lifecycle [here](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/csharp/ms_dotnet_order_of_page_events.htm)

As I said, it is just an example. You may find a better solution.

Hope it helps.